# Problems connecting to an SQL Server 2022 Express, on a Windows 11 Pro machine, from a Windows 10 Pro machine, using Windows Auth

Tags: windows-11, sql-server-2022

From a Windows 10 Pro workstation (in a workgroup) I am having a problem connecting to a SQL Server 2022 Express edition installed on a Windows 11 Pro machine (in the same workgroup), using Windows authentication.

I have setup the SQL Server to allow both Windows and SQL Server users, and have tested connection with a UDL file on the Windows 10 Pro machine. It connects with SQL Server logon, but not with Windows authentication. On the Windows 11 Pro machine, a similar UDL connects both with Windows and SQL Server user authentication.

Likely the OLE DB driver for the two machines are different, though in the UDL on both I select "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server".

On the Windows 10 Pro machine it does show the server name in the dropdown box, and I can select it, but with Windows Authentication I get an error

> [DBNETLIB][Connection Open (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied

as soon as I try to expand the database dropdown box. With SQL Server auth, and after entering SQL user name and password, the database dropdown box shows the available databases on the server, and after selecting one, the test connection reports success.

It is clearly the Windows authentication that is failing, but what is causing it and what can I do to solve it?

I have asked my friend Google and have read countless of Q&A's on various sites and fora (even here on stackoverflow), but so far to no avail. I hope for a bit of luck with this question.

Regards
Soren

Comment: *"in the same workgroup"* That isn't how Windows Authentication works; being in the same workgroup isn't the same thing as being in the same domain. The user accounts are different. The username will be different (`Windows10Devicename\YourUserName` vs `Windows11Devicename\YourUserName`) and will have different underlying SIDs.

Comment: If you check the error logs on  the SQL Server, you'll likely see an error message telling you that no login was found, or that they couldn't be authenticated.

Comment: Thom A: Thanks for your replies. I do know about user accounts and that they are different. With enhancing "Same Workgroup" I meant to say the machines can "see" each other and use each others resources. Also, I do expect windows authentication would accept a request for access from a user authenticated by a login to another machine i the workgroup. But maybe I'm mistaken there.

Comment: Thom A: 1 error in SQL Log: error: 17806:  SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed.

Comment: That the machines can communicate is only relevant for the fact that you make a connection, not authenticate, and the authentication is the problem. You're trying to authenticate to a *remote* device with **local** credentials. That will *not* work. You need a local domain, and you'll need to ensure that you authenticate to that domain, and create an appropriate `LOGIN` on the instance for that domain user.

Comment: Thom A: I see what you mean. Thanks again.